# Conditional BAT File (If Drive Exists) - Run Exe

Tags: batch-file

i'm trying to get an application to run if a certain drive is available, or run the same application locally if it's not.

currently it's launching the application from both locations, am i missing something?

```
@echo off
REM bat file to determine where to launch app
IF EXIST I:\ GOTO launchfromNetwork
ELSE GOTO launchLocally

:launchfromNetwork
START I:\Application.exe

:launchLocally
START C:\ApplicationFolder\Application.exe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In batch files labels are just a place to call or jump, but don't create a barrier for code execution.

```
@echo off
REM bat file to determine where to launch app
IF EXIST I:\ GOTO launchfromNetwork

:launchLocally
START C:\ApplicationFolder\Application.exe
goto :eof

:launchfromNetwork
START I:\Application.exe
goto :eof
```

No need for the `ELSE` clause as if the `IF` is not evaluated to true, code continues execution on the next line, and labels are not barriers.

That is the reason for the `goto :eof` in sample, avoiding the code execution to continue when the next section is reached

Comment: that worked great, many thanks to you MC ND! I will mark yours as 'answered' once the wait time is over, thanks again!